# If $A$ is a symmetric matrix, then can we write $\lambda_{min}(A)\|x\|^2 \leq x^TAx \leq \lambda_{max}(A)\|x\|^2$?

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question and that is, if lets say we have a symmetric matrix $A$ and a vector $x$ of appropriate dimension, then can we have, the famous identity, 
\begin{equation}
\lambda_{min}(A)\|x\|^2 \leq x^TAx \leq \lambda_{max}(A)\|x\|^2
\end{equation}
My main concern is (please correct me if my reasoning is wrong!), this identity holds only when $A$ is diagonalizable or in other words when sum of all the eigenspace is equal to the size of the matrix. Otherwise, will this identity not become something like this?
\begin{equation}
\lambda_{min}(A)\|x\|^2 + \epsilon \leq x^TAx \leq \lambda_{max}(A)\|x\|^2+\epsilon
\end{equation}
The term $\epsilon$ depicting the change due the norm of extra terms that pop up due to the jordan form. Is my reasoning correct? If not, kindly help me find a bound over $x^TAx$ when $A$ happens to be just symmetric.

Comment: Where do the coefficients of $A$ live? Depending on the answer, it may be that $A$ is diagonalisable anyway.

Comment: I'm not following this… If $A$ is symmetric, wouldn't the first inequality give a sufficient bound?

Comment: But isnt the first inequality true only when $A$ is diagonalizable? I mean, what if a matrix that is symmetric and defective, as in leading to some jordan block?

Comment: Again, it is just my reasoning, please feel free to correct.

Comment: [Symmetric real matrices are diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem)